# Recreate Safaris Tab animation open opening / closing a WKWebView

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, wkwebview

so I am trying to recreate that animation in Safari where you have a window open and then click the button to "view all tabs". And then when you tap on an individual window it animated open.

Here is a video of an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfKjo.jpg

I'm using SwiftUI currently but think I might need to do it in UIKit? Anyways, i'll show you what I have so far.

The issue I have is the scaling of the window. In safari it scales so seamlessly, where when I do it you can see it readjust. It's like they just minimize the window in some way.

Anyways, here is what I have. Any ideas would be great! Thanks

```
struct WebViewAnimationTest: View {
    @State var show = false
    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SimpleWebView(url: "https://google.com", fullscreen: show)
                .frame(width: show ? .infinity : 200, height: show ? .infinity : 300)
                .overlay(Color.primary.opacity(0.01))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        show.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "id", in: namespace)
        }
    }
}
```

WEBVIEW:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SimpleWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = WKWebView
    var url: String
    var fullscreen: Bool = false

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let url = URL(string: url)

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        if fullscreen {
            uiView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        } else {
            let actualWidth = (getRect().width - 60)
            let cardWidth = actualWidth / 2

            let scale = cardWidth / actualWidth

            uiView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far. You might want to switch to `LazyVGrid` with `ScrollView`. The idea is to animate changes in scale effect.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebViewAnimationTest()
    }
}

struct WebViewAnimationTest: View {
    @State var show = false
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    let data = SimpleWebView(url: "https://google.com")

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach([data], id: \.id) { view in
                        view
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                            .scaleEffect(show ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    show.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

import WebKit

struct SimpleWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = WKWebView
    var url: String
    var fullscreen: Bool = false
    let id = UUID()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let url = URL(string: url)

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'UIView.transition' like below

```
let webView = WKWebView()
self.view.addSubview(webView)

UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
    webView.isHidden = false
}, completion: nil)

UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    webView.isHidden = true
}, completion: nil)
```